# ST_Intersect and ST_Equals return false positive?

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I try to find equal lines between two table using the following script

```
SELECT tableA.ID, tableB.ID tableA.geom from tableA, tableB
where ST_equals(tableA.geom, tableB.geom)
```

But my problem is that it seem to return all rows (~17000 rows). 
I get the same result if I am using ST_Intersect.

I know that the overlapping geometries are exactly the same, they come from the same source. Not sure what is going on here? I am expecting about 1400 equal/intersecting records.

EDIT: Deleted sample data as it did not really contributed to the question.

Comment: can you add some examples of the geometries?

Comment: Yes i could, how do you think I do that easiest here?

Comment: use the edit button and WKT for a matching pair and a non matching pair

Comment: I added example data for a matching and Not matching pair

Comment: I just ran them individually and then they return t and f as expected. But not if I work with the whole dataset, maybe something is wrong with my initial query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but try:

```
SELECT 
      tableA.ID
      , tableB.ID
      , tableA.geom 
FROM tableA 
inner join tableB ON ST_equals(tableA.geom, tableB.geom)
```

Comment: Thanks I tested it. It also returned all rows. Must be something I am fundamentally missing here. The biggest of the 2 tables has almost 14000 rows, but the result is a bit over 17000

Comment: please retry with the updated code...changed the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN

Comment: Oh yes of course it should be a inner join, thanks for pointing that out! I think the problem is reduced now. Will have another look